# plot ROC curve for classifier

Tags: matlab, classification, matlab-figure, roc

i'm trying to plot a ROC curve for my classifier in matlab.
i have a predicted matrix of 8,000 X 50 binary values (0,1) and test matrix of 8,000 X 50 binary values.  (8000 incidents for 50 targets or classes, for each a class there are 8000 different cases.) 
im using the commands:

```
[tpr,fpr,thresholds] = roc(testy,predy);
plotroc(testy,predy)
```

i expect to get 50 curves with 8,000 points from 0 to 1 of course, but what i get is  50 curves with only 3 points.

here is an example of 10 cases:
[image]

i dont know if use use to commands in the wrong way, or if there is another way to get the ROC curve? thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `perfcurve`:

```
[X,Y] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass);
plot(X,Y);
```

labels are the true labels of the data, scores are the output scores from your classifier (before the threshold) and posclass is the positive class in your labels.

X is false positive rate, Y is true positive rate by default. You can change them as well.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. i tried to use perfcurve but i dont know what to put in the place of posclass. my predictions and true values are  binary values (0,1) so my positive value is 1.